# Delete data after insert bulk statement

Tags: sql, sybase

I did a mistake insert in such way

```
insert into tab1 ( col1 , col2 , col3) select col1 , col2,col3 from tab2
```

I got 7600 row effects

I want to delete those 7600 rows, if I made below delete would it be safe?

```
delete from tab1 where exists  select col1 , col2,col3 from tab2
```

I am asking this to know if I will lost data in tab1. Would this query delete more then 7600 rows? If there was common data I would got unique constraint insert right? ( yes both have the same PK)

Answer (score 0):

Your `DELETE` statement isn't even valid syntax, so I don't think that it will do what you want. Even if you fixed the syntax though, you have nothing relating `tab1` to `tab2`.

Further, you haven't provided your table structures, so anything from here on is mostly a guess on my part. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Try running:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    tab1
INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab2.col1 = tab1.col1  -- Is this the primary key? If not then you'll need to join on the whole primary key
```

If you get the same number as you got when you did the `INSERT` then you can do:

```
DELETE T1
FROM
    Tab1 T1
INNER JOIN Tab2 T2 ON T2.col1 = T1.col1
```

I would put the `DELETE` into a transaction and roll it back once just to verify the count, then if it matches, run it and commit.

Comment: Well thats my question the delete isnt related to insert there is no condition just a bulk if i do the opposit of the insert .. the delete would be the same .. the ddl of table wont help u bcz they are identical .. and i know how to ask questions . But what is the difference between inner join and the bulk insert